# Applied Survival Analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I seem to have issues handling the basics of the topic. Any recommendations for literature/site/examples?

I had problems in specific with the syntax of 'survfit' and its arguments and plotting KM curves.

Thanks
Liran

Comment: Do you have a specific question? This topic is covered in many openly available resources, including this first hit on google when searching for "survival analysis r tutorial". http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/Rsurv.pdf

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is nothing wrong with your question per se, but please note that ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 4):

A nice example that comes to my mind, is that in the R section of the Computer Appendix in the book ["Survival Analysis: A Self-Learning Text"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441966455)

Some other links (found by googling)

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/asa/asa_ch2_r.htm

http://www.stat.nus.edu.sg/~stachenz/Rsurv.pdf

http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~deepayan/SIBS2005/slides/survival.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this definitive guide [A Package for Survival Analysis in S](http://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/tr53pdf/DOC-10027379) by Terry M. Therneau who is the author of the original `survival` package for S (and its version for R).